# Magento 2 - uiComponent doesnt paginate properly neither export

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, grid, uicomponent

I am trying to make a grid on the admin panel with a custom collection (custom dataSource).

The problem I am facing is that it doesnt paginate properly (all records are in one page but the pagination component is shown in the grid). Also I cannot export it as CSV, it gives error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Not registered handle myvendor_orderreport_listing_data_source
```

[image]

My Controller looks like this:

```
    <?php
namespace MyVendor\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Orderreport;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

/**
 * Class Index
 * @package MyVendor\Reports\Controller\Adminhtml\Orderreport
 */
class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'MyVendor_Reports::myreports_order_report';

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    public $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Order Report Grid page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu(self::ADMIN_RESOURCE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Order Report'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

ui Data Provider:

```
    <?php

namespace MyVendor\Reports\Ui\DataProvider\Listing;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;

/**
 * Class OrderReportListing
 * @package MyVendor\Reports\Ui\DataProvider\Listing
 */
class OrderReportListing extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    private $_collection;

    /**
     * OrderReportListing constructor.
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param Reporting $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        StoreManager $storeManager,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Reporting $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            $reporting,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $request,
            $filterBuilder,
            $meta,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $this->_collection
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at',
                array(
                    'from' => date("Y-m-d H:s:i", strtotime('2020-01-01' . ' 23:59:59')),
                    'to' => date("Y-m-d H:s:i", strtotime('2020-07-02' . ' 23:59:59'))
                ));

        $storeIds = array();
        $allowedStoreIds = array_keys($this->_storeManager->getStores());
        $storeIds = array_intersect($allowedStoreIds, $storeIds);
        if (empty($storeIds)) {
            $storeIds = $allowedStoreIds;
        }
       $storeIds = array_values($storeIds);
        $this->_collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));

        $this->_collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('order_payment' => 'sales_order_payment'),
            'order_payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id'
        )->columns(array('increment_id', 'base_tax_amount', 'base_shipping_amount', 'order_currency_code', 'grand_total', 'status'))
            ->where('order_payment.cc_trans_id is not null');


        foreach ($this->_collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $item['order_currency_code3'] = $item['order_currency_code'];
            $item['order_currency_code2'] = $item['order_currency_code'];
        }

        return $this->_collection->toArray();
    }

}
```

Layout (app/code/MyVendor/Reports/view/adminhtml/layout/myreports_orderreport_index.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="myvendor_orderreport_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

uiComponent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing.myvendor_orderreport_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing.myvendor_orderreport_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing_columns</item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="myvendor_orderreport_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\Reports\Ui\DataProvider\Listing\OrderReportListing</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">increment_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">increment_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing.myvendor_orderreport_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">myvendor_orderreport_listing.myvendor_orderreport_listing.myvendor_orderreport_listing_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </container>

    <columns name="myvendor_orderreport_listing_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">increment_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="increment_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="order_currency_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CurrencyIsoCode</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="base_shipping_amount">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ECS__Shipping_Total__c</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="order_currency_code2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CurrencyIsoCode</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="base_tax_amount">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ECS__Tax_Total__c</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="class_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CustTaxGrp</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_taxvat">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CustVATNum</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="order_currency_code3" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CurrencyIsoCode</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="grand_total">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ECS__Total_Order_Amount__c</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated
Thanks